# django sending email (delivery report)

Tags: python, django, email, report

I'm a beginner who is trying to use "Django" to send mail to multiple recipients.
How could I get a delivery report that tells me that: "the mail delivered to recipients a,b,c and d".
"The delivery failed to recipient (e) because his mail box is full".
The delivery failed to recipient (f) because your message considered as spam".

Comment: `"The delivery failed to recipient (f) because your message considered as spam"` Is that even a thing...to be notified that your email message was considered spam...?

Comment: no am just giving examples :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of send_mail() is a boolean that tells whether or not the message was successfully sent.

You can write a function that iterates through the list of recipients, calls send_mail(), appends the successful deliveries to one list, and appends the unsuccessful recipients to another. Then you can write messages using that information. Something like this:

```
    recipients = [ ... ]  # list of people you're sending the email to
    successful_recipients = []
    unsuccessful_recipients = []
    for recipient in recipients:
        if send_mail( ... ):
            successful_recipients.append(recipient)
        else:
            unsuccessful_recipients.append(recipient)
```

It may be difficult/impossible to get the cause of failure, because Django isn't providing you with that information.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/

Comment: Thanks alot sir, but could help me how could I iterate through the list of recipients (by codes) because I am a newbie :D